# Replace paragraph HTML element with line breaks (\r\n\r\n) in php

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, line-breaks

Most answers here are about converting line breaks to `<p>` but I'm looking to do the opposite. I need `<p>` to be `\r\n\r\n`.

Because the WCFM marketplace plugin for WordPress is forcing the use of HTML elements but I need to output my description as JSON object as below, without HTML.

```
{
    "name": "Hijo",
    "description": "<p>Too cute to avoid. You'd so wanna bring her home.</p><p>Each of our pets is .....",
}
```

Or is there an opposite function to wpautop()?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to swap the strings.

```
$description = "<p>Too cute to avoid. You'd so wanna bring her home.</p><p>Each of our pets is </p><p>3rd Line.....";

$descriptionLf = strtr($description,['<p>' => '','</p>' => "\r\n\r\n"]);

echo '<pre>'.$descriptionLf.'</pre>';
```

Note: The special characters like \n must be in double quotes.

Output:

```
Too cute to avoid. You'd so wanna bring her home.

Each of our pets is 

3rd Line.....
```

Comment: I did what u said like `$return = strtr($return,['<p>' => '','</p>' => "\r\n\r\n"]);` and I got a `null`

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_match function to find and replace the `<p>` with `\r\n`, an `</p>` with blank space